# Exporting as a vector image

Tags: vector, export, illustrator

I am trying to create a transit map with certain details such as landmarks and important centers for reference in it.

I have mapped the lines and stops ion QGIS (2.16.2). The base map is Google street maps.

What I want to do is take this whole project as a vector image, and place it somehow in Illustrator, so I can work with the map as a reference to design the map.

What this will allow me to do is use the simplest property of a vector image- the ability to zoom in to parts and view in detail. Not only will I be zooming in the AI document, but also the map so I can view and edit in parallel.

Currently, I am using  a raster image which pixelates a lot when I zoom in.

Any idea how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export your map in the [QGIS Composer](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/print_composer.html) to SVG format, and maybe other vector graphics formats of your choice.