# Rendering maps in graphic design software

Tags: qgis, zoom, svg, rendering, illustrator

Is it possible to see a map in adobe illustrator with zoom rendering? What I want to do is use google maps or OSM or any other map as a reference background for a map I am trying to create in illustrator.

I have found vector maps from openvectormaps.com, but these are still vector images-the only difference between a raster image and this is it doesn't get pixelated.. I want to render maps as they zoom, like we can do in GIS software.

I will ask this on the graphicdesign stackexchange as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting as a vector image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243506/exporting-as-a-vector-image)

Comment: Hey. No it is not. I was the one who posted that question, but after working on that  I realized that my problem was a different one so I posted it here.

Comment: Do you realize that what you call "render as they zoom" is completely changing the image according to the zoom level? Looks like you are asking for a WMS inside AI.

Comment: Yes I do realize that.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/93101/rendering-maps-in-illustrator

Comment: If your expecting Illustrator to do a GIS software job (zoom filtering) you cannot, you would be better off using GIS to do this.